# PHP: Confusion in if condition

Tags: php

I trying to print simple numbers from 1 to 10 using a for loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
  if($i != 4 || $i != 6){
      echo $i."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I just want the output from 0 to 10 but the output should not contain the numbers 4 and 6.

It is working fine if I use the `&&` operator but does not work if I use`||`.

I do not understand why this is not working - I think it should work with `||`.

Comment: *"i think it should work with ||."* - Why do you think so? `$i != 4 || $i != 6` is always true. It could only be false for an `i` which is both `4` and `6` at the same time...

Comment: no, its working with `&&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to print **either** 4 or 6, so you should be using `&&`.

The statement `if($i != 4 || $i != 6)` will trigger whenever `$i` is not equal to 4, **or** whenever `$i` is not equal to 6. Considering 4 is not equal to 6, it will trigger in **both** cases. It will reach `$i = 4`, and realise that `$i` is not equal to 6. This will step into the condition, as you say it only has to hold true for **one or the other**.

The statement `if($i != 4 && $i != 6)` implies that `$i` is not equal to 4 **and** `$i` is not equal to 6. **Both** conditions must hold true at the same time. When `$i = 4`, `$i != 6` will be **true**, but  `$i != 4` will be **false**. Both conditions need to be true, so it will fail. Essentially, this could be rewritten as:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
  if($i != 4) {
    if($i != 6) {
      echo $i."<br/>";
    }
  }
}
```

To skip over the numbers 4 and 6 in the loop, you have to use the **`and`** condition:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
  if($i != 4 && $i != 6){
      echo $i."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You want `&&`.  It would not work with `||`; that means something different.

"x && y" means "only true if x is true and y is also true; otherwise false."

"x || y" means "true if either x is true or y is true; only false if both are false."

The contrapositive (i.e., "opposite") of `($i != 4 && $i != 6)` is `($i == 4 || $i == 6)`.

Mixing in the `||` without swapping the comparisons as well means, in your case, "true if `$i` is not 4, or also true if `$i` is not 6."  Since one of those cases must always true, the result is also always true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) {
if ($i != 4 && $i !=6){
    echo $i."<br>";}} 
?>
```

Comment: because your condition is select AND operation, not OR operation for more detail, would you like to reading this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php